# How can I find the points of continuity and differentiability of a given function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I am given the following function:

$$f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{3cm} f(x) = \arcsin \bigg (x - \sqrt{1-x^2} \bigg)$$

where $D$ is the maximum domain of the function.

How can I find the points of continuity of this function? I've found point of continuity before, but only for piece-wise functions, nothing like this. Also, given the points of continuity, how can I find the points of differentiability and even more interesting, how are the points of differentiability different from the points in which the function has a derivative? Are they the same? If not, how do they differ?

Comment: Start with what you know, what is the domain of $\arcsin(x)$ ? I'm assuming "points of differentiability" refers to where the derivative exists.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm assuming the same thing, but I am not sure. Well, the domain of $\arcsin(x)$ is $[-1, 1]$, but how does that help me? What can I find using this fact, especially since my function is $\arcsin(x - \sqrt{1-x^2})$ and not simply $\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: well, figure out if your function inside attains values beyond $[-1,1]$. That means optimize it. First what is the domain of the function on the inside? That will give you end points.

Comment: @NinadMunshi By "the domain of the function on the inside" you mean the function $x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$? So that means I have to find the domain of $x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$? If so, well, we have the condition that $1-x^2 \ge 0$ and that means that $x \in [0,1]$.So the inside function is defined only for $x \in [0, 1]$. If I input these end points in the function $x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ I get the values $-1$ (if I input $0$) and $1$  (if I input $1$), so $\arcsin(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})$ is always defined for these values. Does that mean that the function $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Your domain for the inside is incorrect, it is not [0,1], so you have reached the correct conclusion incorrectly.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well what is it then? If it's not $[0, 1]$, what is it and why? What did I forget to consider?

Comment: $1-x^2\geq 0$ implies what? Learn to diagnose your own mistakes, especially when you are told where it happens.